# Cannot Find X509Certificate Certificate in Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, x509certificate

I am trying to find the certificate using this code on Virtual Machine.

```
       X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
       certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
       X509Certificate2Collection certs = certificateStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumb, false);
        if (certs.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find the certificate with thumbprint:" + certThumb);
            return;
        }
        certificateStore.Close();
```

I have imported the certificates in Personal folder using Cert Manager.

This code work on my local machine. But it does not works on Virtual Machine(here also i have imported the certificate properly). Don't know what could be the issue.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing (from your previous question and this one) that you're trying to run Service Management API operation from your role. The reason you're getting this error is because the user account in which your application is running in the virtual machine does not have permission to the certificate store. Do take a look at this blog post which talks about how you can consume Service Management API from web/worker role: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asgoyal/archive/2013/07/23/consuming-service-management-api-from-web-worker-role.aspx

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. I will refer this blog and will post the result.

Comment: Awesome! Inspired by this post, I also wrote a similar blog post which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/07/25/consuming-windows-azureservice-management-api-from-webworker-rolethe-easy-way/. Do give it a try as well.